# Implementation of 7Zip in JAVA

Tags: java, aes, 7zip

I have downloaded the LZMA SDK from the 7zip website but to my disappointment it does only support compression and decompression and does not support AES crypto.  Does anyone know if there is any implementation of 7zip with AES crypto completely in JAVA?.  Thanks.

Regards,
Kal.

Answer (score 4):

From  apache  common-compress  documentation:

> Note that Commons Compress currently only supports a subset of compression and encryption algorithms used for 7z archives. For writing only uncompressed entries, LZMA, LZMA2, BZIP2 and Deflate are supported - in addition to those reading supports AES-256/SHA-256 and DEFLATE64.

If  you  use common-compress  you probably will not have  issues with  portability  of  your  code  as  you don't have  to  embed any  native  libraries.

Below code  shows  how to iterate  over  files  within 7zip archive and print its  contents to stdout.  You can adapt it  for  AES requirements  :

```
public static void showContent(String archiveFilename) throws IOException {

    if (archiveFilename == null) {
        return;
    }

    try (SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(archiveFilename))) {
        SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
                final byte[] contents = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
                int off = 0;
                while ((off < contents.length)) {
                    final int bytesRead = sevenZFile.read(contents, off, contents.length - off);
                    off += bytesRead;
                }
                System.out.println(new String(contents, "UTF-8"));              
            entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

Imports  used:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile;
```

Maven Dependencies  Used:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
        <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please  note:  org.tukaani:xz  is required  for  7zip  only.  common-compress  dependency  doesn't need  it  for  other  supported  compression formats.

Comment: Since I was looking for it, let me be clear: Commons Compress does not support writing encrypted 7z files.

Comment: To get writing of encrypted 7z files, it looks like native bridging https://github.com/borisbrodski/sevenzipjbinding is the go.

Answer (score 3):

According 7Zip team:

> LZMA SDK doesn't support crypto
>   methods. Use 7-Zip source code
>   instead.

The source code is available in assembler, C and C++, you can call them from Java.

Comment: Source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/forums/forum/45797/topic/3808144